# Jsf's log page is always showed

Tags: jsf

Now I want to use p:log to show some logs on the page. But the log page is always showed on the main page. I can't find its related attribute to control the showing of log page. It also can't be closed, such as some button. Can someone give some messages about this? Thanks.

```
<h:form> 
    <p:log  />  
</h:form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the rendered attribute which according to Primefaces documentation is a "Boolean value to specify the rendering of the component, when set to false component will not be rendered".

```
<h:form> 
    <p:log rendered="#{YourBean.yourCondition}"  />  
</h:form>
```

In your backing bean you would need to  have:

```
public Boolean getYourCondition()
{
   return yourCondition;
}
```